# Compute next prime number in Haskell

Tags: function, loops, testing, haskell, recursion

I am trying to compute the next closest prime number after a number is entered with Haskell,
I have coded 2 functions `isPrime` and `nextPrime`

Here is my code:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x   | x < 2          = False
        | otherwise      = prime (2:[3,4..(x-1)])
where 
    prime (y:z)
        | x < y ^ 2      = True
        | x `mod` y == 0 = False
        | otherwise      = prime z



nextPrime :: Int -> Int
nextPrime n | isPrime n == True = n
            | otherwise = nextPrime n
        where
            n = n + 1
```

The problem I have is that I get this error when I run it : *** Exception: "<<"loop">>"

I don't know what's wrong, is it an infinite loop?

Comment: Other people have answered the question about what's wrong, but just to be clear: Yes, `<<loop>>` indicates that your code has an infinite loop, and that the GHC runtime detected this.  It can't do this for all loops, but it's pretty magical when it does.

Comment: When you write `2:[3,4..(x-1)]`, do you mean `2:[3,5..(x-1)]`?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the value of variables in Haskell. This means that you cannot execute

```
n = n + 1
```

since that would change the value of `n`. In Haskell, `n` is a name that *always* refers to the same value inside the function it is used. If `n` starts out as `3`, `n` will *always* be `3`. You could do,

```
next = n + 1
```

and then also change

```
| otherwise = nextPrime n
```

into

```
| otherwise = nextPrime next
```

This will not change the value of any variable, but instead create a new variable with the new value – something you often do in Haskell!

Comment: Good answer - beat me by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 3):

Just change the definition of `nextPrime` to

```
nextPrime :: Int -> Int
nextPrime n | isPrime n = n   -- don't need to compare to True here
            | otherwise = nextPrime (n+1)
```

You generate an infinite regress when you try to define `n = n + 1`, as the runtime would attempt to expand this as

```
n =   n + 1
  =  (n + 1) + 1
  = ((n + 1) + 1) + 1
  = ...
```

Fortunately, the compiler is able to detect this kind of infinite regress and warn you about it!

Comment: It is working the only problem now is that if you enter a prime number, it returns the prime number and not the next one.
i.e. if you enter 2, you get 2 - same for 3, 5, 7 ...
What can I add to sort this out?

Comment: Well, one quick fix would be to rename the function you already have to `nextPrime_helper` and define a new function, `nextPrime n = nextPrime_helper (n+1)`. Pretty ugly, but it works!

Comment: Isn't there a neater way of doing this, without defining a new function.

Comment: @sachalondon You could do, for example, `| isPrime next = next | otherwise = nextPrime (next+1)`. This will always check "one number ahead" so if you give it `2`, it will first try with `3` and then continue to `4` and so on.

Comment: @kqr I have tried what you've said, so I have : 
`nextPrime :: Int -> Int 
nextPrime n | isPrime next = next
            | otherwise = nextPrime (next + 1)
        where
            next = n + 1`
But it does not work when I try it out it gets stuck and does not give an answer..

Comment: @sachalondon I'm sorry, I made a mistake when writing that comment. There's a simple bug (a logic error) in the code I wrote, and I'm sure you can find it and correct it if you try to think about what really happens!

Comment: @kqr Yes of course it should be `otherwise = nextPrime (n + 1)` :)

Comment: @sachalondon Correct! Or alternatively, since `n+1` is the same thing as `next`, you could write `otherwise = nextPrime next`. Which one you choose depends on which you think is the most readable and easy to understand!